# Why doesn't this simple HTML/JavaScript calculator work?

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header></header>

<body>
  <label id="FirstNumber">First Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="number1">
  <br>
  <label id="SecondNumber">Second Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="number2">
  <br>
  <button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button id="multiply" onclick="multiply()">Multiply</button>
  <br>
  <label id="FinalNumberLabel">Answer:</label>
  <label id="Answer"></label>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function add() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById("number1");
      var num2 = document.getElementById("number2");
      var answer = num1 + num2;
      document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;
    }

    function multiply() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById("number1");
      var num2 = document.getElementById("number2");
      var answer = num1 * num2;
      document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The "Multiply" button returns a "NaN" error and the Add button always returns "[objectHTMLInputElement][objectHTMLInputElement]"

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Calculating with element objects might be hard. Use their values converted to numbers instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting the values, just the elements:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("number1");
```

In this case `num1` isn't actually a number, it's an `objectHTMLInputElement`.

You probably want to start with something like:

```
var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value);
```

Perhaps also add some error checking, or specify that the inputs need to be numeric, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. .value -> you do not want the input element, you want the value it holds
2. parseInt -> you want number not string (or parseFloat if you want floats)

   ```
   function add() {
     var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
     var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
     var answer = num1 + num2;
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;
   }

   function multiply() {
     var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
     var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
     var answer = num1 * num2;
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;
   }
   ```